# Bash Script with PHP code

Tags: php, bash, urldecode

I have a bash script that has as a variable a urlencoded string, that I want to be decoded. I know this can be done with bash, but I thought I might as well just call a the PHP function urldecode() and be done with it.

I would have preferred to run the php function in the bash code, but I opted to write a very simple script

```
<?php
   echo urldecode($argv);
?>
```

and call this script in the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
...#$MYURL is an encoded url
...
$MYURL="php myurldecodescript.php -- $MYURL"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.
How is it best to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, using PHP, without having to create the `myurldecodescript.php` file. If you supply a `-r` option to PHP, it will run code that you specify in the command line. So you can do this:

```
MYURL=`php -r "echo urldecode('$MYURL');"`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
MYURL=$(php myurldecodescript.php -- "$MYURL")
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$MYURL="php myurldecodescript.php $MYURL"
```

not sure that the `--` will work (I'm no bash expert !!) .... and in PHP do

```
echo urldecode($argv[1]);
```

[`$argv` is an array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
echo $MYURL | sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g' | xargs echo -e
```

Comment: wow ... that looks a little different to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10194406/572939) - perhaps i should stay away from these `bash` tagged questions !!!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
MYURL=$(php -r 'echo urldecode($argv[1]);' "$MYURL")
```